# Relation between Different frequencies in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python, raspberry-pi-os

I am new to the field of RPi wherein I need to interface sensor-ADC-RPi.

I have repeatedly come across terms like

1. Core frequency of CPU.
2. maximum sampling rate provided by ADC
3. Nyquist sampling frequency
4. I2C bus frequency

In embedded systems, how these four frequencies are related to each other.

So if someone could please explain this how I would go about, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not related in any way.

Each piece of hardware will have frequencies it supports.

The maximum frequency supported by the SPI bus depends on the SPI hardware.

The maximum frequency supported by the I2C bus depends on the I2C hardware.

The maximum frequency supported by the ADS1015 depends on the ADS1015 hardware (as documented in its datasheet).

As for the Nyquist frequency look at a wiki.